# How long does "bikur cholim" last?

Tags: mitzvah, choleh-sick

When someone [visits the sick](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Visiting_the_Sick) and fulfils the mitzvah of bikur cholim, when is he "finished" or is he constantly fulfilling the mitzvah as [long](https://torah.org/torah-portion/weekly-halacha-5772-vayechi/) as the choleh wants him to stay?

If he is constantly fulfilling it during his visit, is he patur from other mitzvot during the entirety of the visit because of [oseik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osek_b%27mitzvah_patur_min_hamitzvah) b'mitzvah patur min hamitzvah?

Comment: We have people who visit sick patients in my neighborhood nursing home. If the rabbi needs these visitors for a minyan, it seems that they are required to help make the minyan. Thus, I think the mitzvah ends almost immediately - i.e. at the point that you enter the room and make yourself known to the patient. (From my understanding, the patient need not acknowledge your presence. As a matter of fact, in such situations, I think your *oseik bemitva* ends almost immediately.)

Comment: Isn't this an explicit Mishna? חולים ומשמשיהם פטורים מן הסוכה

Comment: @DoubleAA It's possible that if you are actually serving / helping them, it may be a different situation. I think this is esp. true if you are someone helping a "dangerously" ill person who requires continuous watching, e.g. someone who might fall out of bed. A visitor is not the same as a שמש.

Comment: Once heard from Rabbi Hershel Schachter Shlit"a, that the Rambam writes the word וצא, and he should leave, by Bikkur Cholim. Sometimes people don't realize the patient needs his rest. The Rambam is saying sometimes it is a Mitzva to leave too.